# Проблема с админкой в Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет! Работал нормально с админкой все хорошой. Но сегодня когда я вхожу в админ панель ([http://мойсайт/wp-admin](http://%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/wp-admin)) выдает след. окно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что это за бред? Как нибудь можно отключить или сбросить пароль имея доступ к БД?

Comment: Обратитесь в службу поддержки вашего хостинга. Если вы не ставили пароль на файл/папку админки, значит вероятно ваш хостер побеспокоился о вас.

Comment: Думаю очень часто обращались серверу или скрипту, и возможно скрипт сам временно заблокировал Вас